# How do I save classifier's most informative features into a variable? (Python NLTK)

Tags: python, classification, nltk, training-data

Say I have this snippet of code:

```
classifier.show_most_informative_features(10)
```

Python will display 10 features along with their pos,neg tags.
Is there any way to save the features into a variable?

Comment: Does the `classifier` object have a method to return those features instead of just displaying them, or an instance variable which holds them? That's where I would look. Your question is actually how to get the content shown by the method instead of just displaying it, having a variable refer to `None` won't do you any good.

Answer (score 0):

The method `show_most_informative_features()` prints out the requested features, and returns `None`. To return a list of feature names and "informativeness", use this:

```
features = classifier.most_informative_features(10)
```

You'll get a list of pairs that could be displayed like this:

```
for f, w in features:
    print(f, w)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution works on python3, saved to output_string variable.

```
from io import StringIO
import contextlib
import sys

@contextlib.contextmanager
def stdout_redirect(where):
    sys.stdout = where
    try:
        yield where
    finally:
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

with stdout_redirect(StringIO()) as new_stdout:
    classifier.show_most_informative_features(15)

new_stdout.seek(0)

# output assigned to variable
output_string = new_stdout.read()
```